# How to change UTF-8 encoding in php?

Tags: php

i convert my html page in to .php but it display the error that

> The document's current encoding can't correctly save all of the
>   characters within the document.you may want to change to UTF-8 or an
>   encoding that supports the special characters in this document.

but in my file its already set  then why displaying this messege.?

Comment: which document writer you are using because it was my problem when i was using notepad ++ then i chosed encoding as encode as UTF-8 without bom

Comment: On Mac OSX you can use for example BBEdit.

Comment: What is giving you the error? The text editor? PHP itself?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this at the top of page

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
```

Comment: (A) There is no indication in the question that MySQL is involved at all, so there is no reason to believe that this is the answer. (B) Even if this were the solution, this is not a helpful answer. It should include some explanation as to _why_ it would fix the problem.